# How can I make everything in a div expand with the same proportion with transitions

Tags: html, css

I have a section of my page under a div with an image and different sized text. On hover, I want everything to grow larger, but retain the same proportions. How can I do this without manually finding the perfect transition sizes for each element inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just transform the div

```css
div:hover{
  transform:scale(0.8);
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: transform 200ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/458/354?image=0" alt="hi" width="300px" >
  <br>
  <h1> hello there </h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the scale transformation linked to a css3 transition though? I'm trying
 transition: scale 1s linear;
but it doesn't work

Comment: edited the answer.. you need `transition: transform 1s` and not `scale`